# There is only so much you can remember. (In which context, can this sentence be used?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There is only so much you can remember.
> (A particular amount, often a large or excessive amount)

I came across this sentence in a dictionary.

In which context, can this sentence be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**so** in this context means "to a certain extent or degree", so **so much** means something like "the amount specified."  Informally, "there's only so much" means "there is only a limited amount", so you might use it in a context like

> I know this is a lot to learn at once, so don't be afraid to ask again if you forget something.  There is only so much you can remember.

Comment: Does the example sentence mean "You only need to remember few things"? or "Our brain can't remember everything."?

Comment: It means "Our brains can't remember everything".  You can tell this because of the word **can**.  If we meant "need to", we might say "There's only so much you need (or *have to*) to remember."